# Php array function

Tags: php, arrays

```
 array1 = Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [direction_id] => 3
                    [direction_name] => Hamza
                    [direction_type_name] => Metro
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [direction_id] => 4
                    [direction_name] => Alisher Navoiy
                    [direction_type_name] => Metro
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [direction_id] => 2
                    [direction_name] => Bunyodkor
                    [direction_type_name] => Metro
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [direction_id] => 1
                    [direction_name] => Skver
                    [direction_type_name] => Orienter
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [direction_id] => 6
                    [direction_name] => Mustaqillik maydoni
                    [direction_type_name] => Orienter
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [direction_id] => 5
                    [direction_name] => Bobur parki
                    [direction_type_name] => Orienter
                )

        )
```

I have array1 array. I want change this array like this:

```
array1 = Array
    (
        [Metro] => Array
            (
                [direction_id] => 3
                [direction_name] => Hamza
                [direction_id] => 4
                [direction_name] => Alisher Navoiy    
                [direction_id] => 2
                [direction_name] => Bunyodkor 

            )


        [Orienter] => Array
            (
                [direction_id] => 1
                [direction_name] => Skver
                [direction_type_name] => Orienter
                [direction_id] => 6
                [direction_name] => Mustaqillik maydoni
                [direction_id] => 5
                [direction_name] => Bobur parki
            )

    )
```

How can I do it?

Comment: And...how do you know the value of $array1['Metro']['direction_id']?

Answer (score 4):

You can't like that. You can't repeat keys. They need to be unique.

You probably want something like this:

```
[Metro] => Array
    (
        0 => array(
            [direction_id] => 3
            [direction_name] => Hamza
        ),
        1 => array(
            [direction_id] => 4
            [direction_name] => Alisher Navoiy    
        )
            ...
```

What you need to do is use the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct to loop your original array and reorganize the data the way you want to.

*... or wait for someone to post the exact code you need in one of the answers.*

Answer (score 1):

you cant really do that, because you cant have 2 keys being the same per array, but what you can do is:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $val){
     if(!isset($newArray[$val['direction_type_name']])){
         $newArray[$val['direction_type_name']] = array();
     }
     $newArray[$val['direction_type_name']][] = array(
                                      'direction_id' => $val['direction_id'],
                                      'direction_name' => $val['direction_name']
                                        )
}
```

it would end up being something like

```
$newArray = Array (
  [Metro] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array (
               [direction_id] => 3
               [direction_name] => Hamza
            )

            [1] => Array (
               [direction_id] => 4
               [direction_name] => Alisher Navoiy    
            )
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$resultArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    if(!array_key_exists($array1[$i]['direction_type_name'], $resultArray) {
        $resultArray[$array1[$i]['direction_type_name']] = array();
    }
    $resultArray[$array1[$i]['direction_type_name']][] = array('direction_id' => $array1[$i]['direction_id'], 'direction_name' => $array1[$i]['direction_name']);
}

print_r($resultArray);
?>
```

Didn't test it, but hope it works...

Comment: This also works, besides, of course, the fact that you are missing a right parentheses on your if statement :)

Comment: Yes, one more closing bracket...sorry for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something simple like an iteration over your big array:
You create 2 other arrays : Metro and Orienter
For all item in your big array :
 if direction_type_name == Metro, then you add the informations to the Metro array, otherwise you add the information to Orienter array